# Simplify fractions

Tags: python, modulo

I'm learning python and im trying to make a function to simplify fractions, if I E.G have 20/25, I want that to print 4/5.

```
numerator= 20
denominator= 25
common = denominator
if numerator < denominator:
    common = numerator
if common < 1:
    if numerator % common == 0 or denominator % common == 0:
        numerator %= common ;
        denominator %= common 
    common += 1
print('Simplified:', int(numerator) , '/', int(denominator))
```

This is what I'm working with now, duno if my brain stopped working but can't get further. Can anyone help me out where im thinking wrong?

Edit: Without using further modules

Comment: Use the greatest common divisor function (`math.gcd`).

Comment: any way without importing modules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fraction module

```
from fractions import  Fraction
numerator= 20
denominator= 25

fraction_value = Fraction(numerator,denominator)
print(fraction_value)
```

Output

```
4/5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import `math.gcd`, make your own:

```py
def gcd(x, y):
    while y != 0:
        (x, y) = (y, x % y)
    return x

numerator = 20
denominator = 25

common = gcd(numerator, denominator)
# integer division since you know gcd must be a factor
numerator //= common
denominator //= common

print(f"{numerator}/{denominator}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer that just divides the numerator and denominator by all the integers that came before them, if divisible.

```
def fraction(numerator, denominator):
    for i in range(2, numerator+1):
         while numerator % i == 0 and denominator % i == 0:
            numerator /= i
            denominator /= i
    return f"{int(numerator)}/{int(denominator)}"
```

Here is another solution that just divides by prime numbers and also takes care of improper fractions:

```
def fraction(numerator, denominator):
    # Take care of improper fractions.
    whole_number = int(numerator/denominator)
    numerator -= whole_number * denominator

    # List contraction to generate prime numbers
    primes = [x for x in range(2, numerator+1) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]

    # Repeatedly divide numerator and denominator by prime numbers
    for index in range(len(primes)):
        while numerator % primes[index] == 0 and denominator % primes[index] == 0:
            numerator /= primes[index]
            denominator /= primes[index]

    # Format differently for proper and improper fractions
    if whole_number == 0:
        return f"{int(numerator)}/{int(denominator)}"
    return f"{whole_number} {int(numerator)}/{int(denominator)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own GCD function:

```py
def GCD(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        t = b
        b = a % b
        a = t
    return a if a != 0 else None

def fixnstr(s):
    s = s.rstrip("0").rstrip(".")
    if len(s) == 0:
        s = "0"
    return s

n = float(input("Enter the numerator: "))
d = float(input("Enter the denominator: "))

gcd = GCD(n, d)
n = fixnstr(str(n/gcd))
d = fixnstr(str(d/gcd))
print("Simplify: "+n+"/"+d)
```

This also removes extra `0`s and decimal points when possible, and `n` and `d` are `str`ings.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing each term by their gcd will give you the simplified fraction:

```
def gcd(a,b):  return b if a<1 else gcd(b%a,a) # or use math.gcd
def frac(n,d): c=gcd(n,d);return n//c,d//c
```

For example:

```
frac(20,25)       --> (4,5)
frac(25,20)       --> (5,4)
frac(12345,67890) --> (823, 4526)
frac(14641, 4913) --> (14641, 4913)

print("Simplified: {}/{}".format(*frac(20,25)))

# Simplified: 4/5
```